# How to implement calendar feature in flutter to display a date after the present date till 2 days after in a DateTimePickerFormField

Tags: flutter

I want my calendar in flutter to start displaying the dates from a day after the present date to two days after.

```
final dateFormat = DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_US");

new DateTimePickerFormField(
                  dateOnly: true,
                  format: dateFormat,
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val != null) {
                      return null;
                    } else {
                      return 'Date field is empty';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Departure Date'),
                  initialValue: DateTime.now(),
                  //difference: finalValue.difference(initialValue).inDays,
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    debugPrint(value.toString());
                  },
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `add` function of `DateTime` class:

```
   final dateFormat = DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_US");

   new DateTimePickerFormField(
              inputType: InputType.date,
              format: dateFormat,
              validator: (val) {
                if (val != null) {
                  return null;
                } else {
                  return 'Date field is empty';
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Departure Date'),
              initialDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)),
              firstDate: DateTime.now(),
              lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3)),
              onSaved: (value) {
                debugPrint(value.toString());
              },
            ),
```

And by the way I changed your code from using `dateOnly` parameter to `inputType` because the former is now deprecated and using it will cause you future compatibility issues.

Comment: Hello Ibrahim, thank you very much, I implemented your response but the calendar is no longer available unless i comment out firstDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 1)), and when i comment it out the firstDate does not work but the lastDate works.

Comment: firstDate: DateTime.now() without the .add(new Duration(days: 1)), fixed the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well I was in the process to solve the first issue but I'm glad to hear that you managed to solve it. Not at all !